# Serial port two way communication problems

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, pyserial

I have a device (that is coded in CPP) connected to my Ubuntu PC, and I am attempting to communicate with it using my Python node. Basically the attempt is to receive messages from the device, and then send messages to it (Baud rate is 230400). By default, the device only publishes a heartbeat message at a very low freq. : 0.1- 0.2 Hz. The messages that are sent to the device are around 2 Hz. (they can be up to 200 Hz when I finish my complete implementation). In the default case, I am able to receive the heartbeat and send my messages properly from the PC.

But because I needed more information than just the heartbeat, I included some more messages to be sent from the device, increased the frequency to about 2 Hz. But then, I am able to receive those messages from the device properly, but the messages I am sending to the device drop after some time. On the PC end, the sender + receiver are packaged into the same Python script. If I relaunch the script, it works again for a small amount of time, then stops.

The amount of time it takes to stop decreases as I increase the amount of data being sent from device to the PC or its frequency.

To recap:

Case 1: Device sending at 0.1 Hz, PC sending at 2 Hz, sending/receiving fine work on both ends.

Case 2: Device sending at >1-2 Hz, PC sending at 2 Hz, Device sends, PC receives. PC sends, device stops receiving after some time.

The way the port is opened in Python goes like this

```
def __init__(self, device, baud=230400, autoreconnect=False, source_system=255):
    import serial
    self.baud = baud
    self.device = device
    self.autoreconnect = autoreconnect
    self.port = serial.Serial(self.device, self.baud, timeout=0,
                              dsrdtr=False, rtscts=False, xonxoff=False)
```

I am not very knowledgeable about the low level aspects of serial port comms. I have tried tweaking parameters such as buffer sizes, timeouts etc. on the device but nothing worked. It would be very helpful if anyone can shed some light on why this problem is occurring, or what the red flags are that I should look for inside the code. Unfortunately, the complete code that's on the device is quite extensive to display here, so I can include specific portions if needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say "the device stops receiving".  Does that mean the sender stopped?  Or is the sender still sending but the receiver is wedged somehow?

Comment: The sender still sends the messages at the right frequency. It's just that the device on the other end never receives them.

Comment: Other than opening and reading, does the receiver do any other interaction with the serial port?:  Change parameters, write, ioctl(), tcsetattr(), etc.?  How about a spurious close?

Comment: What OS is the "device"? Can you share the device code? Could be LOTS of things - possibly a race-condition where you miss to see the "new data come in".

Comment: Hello, thanks for the replies. I was able to fix the problem: it was in the fact that the device handles send and receive operations in separate threads, and there was some sort of conflict between them. When I rewrote the code with send and receive  operations in the same place, I did not have this "timing out" issue. Hopefully this does not give rise to more issues. 

wallyK: No, there is no more interaction.
Mats: It runs ARM Linux, NuttX. I can edit the question with the code tomorrow, (I don't have it right now), it would be great if you can let me know I am not doing something wrong.